# Can you run Active Directory 2008r2 on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

We are upgrading all domain controllers to Windows Server 2012. But we have some legacy systems which won't work with Active Directory past 2008r2.

Is it possible to run AD 2008r2 without any 2008r2 domain controllers? (All 2012 instead.)

Thanks.

Comment: What specific aspects of your systems can't work with newer AD?  Some aspects of what the domain's doing are controlled by the functional level or GPO, but some security feature defaults will change with the servers, so it's important to know exactly what's incompatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can run AD all the way back to Windows Server 2003 functional level with all-Win2k12 R2 servers.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/understanding-active-directory-functional-levels(v=ws.10).aspx

Whether your application requires the AD be at a functional level, or actually requires the DCs be no newer than 2008 R2, is for you to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just leave AD at the 2008R2 [functional level](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/understanding-active-directory-functional-levels(v=ws.10).aspx)?